# Is it possible to have 1 of 2 form input fields as required fields?

Tags: validation, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using bootstrap to display a search page. Now in this search page I want to have a the user to put in either Name or Title before submit. Thus it is required that ONE of the two fields is put in. So far I did not find anything that supports it, but could be that I overlooked this functionality so far.

Thus my question is here: Is it possible to have 1 out of 2 fields as required with bootstrap? Or do you have to write the whole validation then yourself?

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form" data-toggle="validator">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Name">Name:</label> 
        <input type="text" id="Name" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Title">Title:</label> 
        <input type="text" id="Title" />
    </div>
    <input type="Submit" value="Search" class="searchButton" />
</form>
```

Comment: You can do it only if your fields are `radio` and have the same `name` like here http://jsfiddle.net/hzfy9rqz/1/.
Anyway, this does not require a lot of JS ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap can't help you here. Bootstrap doesn't include any sort of form validation.

Anyway, as Bootstrap uses jQuery it is very simple to roll your own...

```js
$('form').on('submit',function() {
  if ($('#Name').val() === '' &&  $('#Title').val() === '') {
    alert('Please enter either your name or your title');
    return false; /* cancel submit */
  }
  
  /* Passed! */
  /* Forms in snippets won't submit so ... */
  alert("Passed validation");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form class="form-inline" role="form" data-toggle="validator">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Name">Name:</label> 
        <input type="text" id="Name" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Title">Title:</label> 
        <input type="text" id="Title" />
    </div>
    <input type="Submit" value="Search" class="searchButton" />
</form>
```

Or if you have 2 to n required fields and you don't want to hard code the ID's you could do something like htis...

```js
$('form').on('submit',function() {
    var emptyFields = 0;

    $('.required').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() === '') { emptyFields++ }
    });

    if (emptyFields === $('.required').length) {
        alert('Please fill in at least one of the fields');
        return false; /* cancel submit */
    }
    
    /* Passed! */
    /* Forms in snippets won't submit so ... */
    alert("Passed validation");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form class="form-inline" role="form" data-toggle="validator">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Name">Name:</label> 
        <input type="text" id="Name" class="required" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Title">Title:</label> 
        <input type="text" id="Title" class="required" />
    </div>
    <input type="Submit" value="Search" class="searchButton" />
</form>
```